# Computing chromatic number of subcubic graphs

Tags: graph-colouring

According to [graphclasses.org](https://graphclasses.org/classes/gc_720.html), the chromatic number of a subcubic graph can be computed in linear time (because the decision problem COLORABILITY can be solved in linear time). The reference given the website is M. Chlebik and J. Chlebikova, "[Approximation hardness of dominating set problems in bounded degree graphs](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540108000928)".

**Which result of this paper solve the COLORABILITY problem of subcubic graphs in linear time?**
The chromatic number of a subcubic graph is 3 unless it is bipartite or $K_4$ is a component by Brook's theorem. Then, why that particular reference is given? Is this simply a case of wrong reference?

Def. A graph with maximum degree at most three is called a *subcubic graph*.

Comment: I would think it is simply a wrong reference, some of them are added automatically for example. You can e-mail the people at graphclasses.org and they'll be glad to fix it.

Comment: @ChristianKomusiewicz Thanks. I think I did it already [here](https://graphclasses.org/contact.html). I shall send one more mail just in case.